# Spring MVC http REST explanation, POST + GET

Tags: java, http, servlets, spring-mvc

I have a webapp running on Spring SVM running in this direction:

```
http://localhost:8085/mongodb
```

The main controller that handles GET and POST request look looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
    private static final String DATA_FIELD = "Data";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView createDomain(@RequestBody Domain Domain, HttpServletResponse httpresponse, WebRequest request) throws Exception{

        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", "FUCK YOU2");

        Domain createdDomain = Domain;

        logger.info("Post Received" + Domain.toString());

        //Create HTTP Response for the POST request
        httpresponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED.value());

        MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(new Mongo(),"rest_database");
        mongoOps.insert(Domain);


        System.out.println("PRINTED");

        return new ModelAndView("post", DATA_FIELD, createdDomain);
    }

}
```

Apparently the code is working. When I use the Chrome Extension Advanced Rest Client ([here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)) to send POST request the client sends a POST then a GET every time, so I always get the page in the GET method.

The weird thing is that google chrome network developer tool shows a POST request pending and then a GET request that returns OK, the network debugger shows this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7437425/network_debugger.png

When I send this request:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7437425/post_response.png

I would like to know if this is the standard way of sending a POST, by sending a GET shortly afterwards.

A funny thing is that my console never shows the result of this commands:

```
logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", "FUCK YOU2");
System.out.println("PRINTED");
```

This leads me to believe that actually the method that handle POST requests is not running at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `createDomain` is not configured for handling post requests, but only **put** request.

What you are seeing in the debugger is that upon the post request something answers with a redirect to another URL where a get is performed. Yes, this is a pretty standard way of doing things. But this behavior does not come from the code you are showing, but is probably encoded somewhere else. Possibly in some default controllers that handle almost everything.

Comment: Sorry, the PUT was a typo, its corrected on the way all the test were made. Those screens were taken when PUT was POST, I changed it to run a test and forgot the change it back. So are you saying my code is not running the createDomain method?